# Infinitely many primes of the form $\lfloor \sqrt {3} \cdot n \rfloor $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove or disprove following statement :

> There are infinitely many primes of the form : $\lfloor \sqrt {3} \cdot n \rfloor $

Note: This is a problem I made myself.

There is a theorem that states :

$\lfloor nx \rfloor =
\begin{cases}
 n\lfloor x \rfloor, & \text{if } 0 \leq \{x\} < \frac{1}{n} \\
 n\lfloor x \rfloor +1, & \text{if } \frac{1}{n} \leq \{x\} < \frac{2}{n} \\
 n\lfloor x \rfloor +2, & \text{if } \frac{2}{n} \leq \{x\} < \frac{3}{n} \\
 \vdots \\
 n\lfloor x \rfloor +n-1, & \text{if } \frac{n-1}{n} \leq \{x\} < 1 \\
\end{cases}$

where $\{x\}$ is a non-integer part of $x$ .

Hence :

$\lfloor \sqrt{3}\cdot n \rfloor =
\begin{cases}
 n, & \text{if } 0 \leq \sqrt{3}-1 < \frac{1}{n} \\
 n +1, & \text{if } \frac{1}{n} \leq \sqrt{3}-1 < \frac{2}{n} \\
 n +2, & \text{if } \frac{2}{n} \leq \sqrt{3}-1 < \frac{3}{n} \\
 \vdots \\
 2n-1, & \text{if } \frac{n-1}{n} \leq \sqrt{3}-1 < 1 \\
\end{cases}$

How can I proceed from here ?

Comment: I don't know, if this helps... It is easy to see (Beatty's Theorem) that all the positive integers belong to exactly one of the sets 
$$\{[n\sqrt3]\mid n\in\mathbf{Z}_+\}$$
and
$$
\{[n\frac{\sqrt3+3}2]\mid n\in\mathbf{Z}_+\}.$$
This follows because $a=\sqrt3$ and $b=(3+\sqrt3)/2$ are both irrational and satisfy the equation $1/a + 1/b =1$. So it would suffice to show that the primes in the latter set only have a fractional density. Doesn't look any easier, really?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My idea was to apply somehow Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions...but it seems that I cannot use that theorem for this problem...

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @Aryabhata [Beatty sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence)

Comment: @pedja: That is not the source. What I am asking is did you make this problem yourself? Did you get it from someone? Do you know that there is a resolution to this and looking for a way to resolve this?

Comment: @Aryabhata Beatty sequences are well known and this particular question is made by myself so I don't think that there is known solution of this problem..

Comment: @pedja: I know about Beatty sequences. Please mention in the question that you made it yourself...

Comment: @pedja: The reason for this is it is easy to make up problems, but resolving them could be surprisingly hard (eg: Goldbach conjecture). You should make it clear upfront so people know what to expect.

Comment: i am amused about the tag 'elementary-number-theory'

Comment: By the way, this is in Sloane's OEIS: http://oeis.org/A184796

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is too long to be a comment, so I will write it as an answer.

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the interval
$$
I_n=\Bigl[\frac{n}{\sqrt3},\frac{n+1}{\sqrt3}\Bigr].
$$
If $I_n$ contains an integer, then
$$
n=\Bigl\lfloor\sqrt3\,\Bigl\lceil\frac{n}{\sqrt3}\Bigr\rceil\Bigr\rfloor.
$$
If we could prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $I_p\cap\mathbb{N}\ne\emptyset$, then we could answer the question in the affirmative. I wil give a probabilistic argument, assuming that the fractional parts of $p/\sqrt3$, where $p$ runs over all primes, are uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. In that case, the probability that $I_p\cap\mathbb{N}\ne\emptyset$ would be the width of the interval $I_p$, which is $1/\sqrt3=0.577\dots$ Thus, about $57\%$ of all primes should satisfy $I_p\cap\mathbb{N}\ne\emptyset$.
Computation shows that $576874$ of the first $10^6$ primes verify the condition.

### Edit

According to Aryabhata's comment, $\bigl\{\,\{p\,\sqrt3\,\bigr\}: p \text{ is prime}\}$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. Then there are an infinite number of primes $p$ such that $I_p\cap\mathbb{N}\ne\emptyset$ and
$$
p=\Bigl\lfloor\sqrt3\,\Bigl\lceil\frac{p}{\sqrt3}\Bigr\rceil\Bigr\rfloor.
$$

The same argument shows that given an irrational $\alpha>0$ there are infinite primes of the form $\lfloor\alpha\,n\rfloor$.

Comment: $\{p_n \alpha\}$ is equidistributed in $(0,1)$ for irrational $\alpha$ ($p_n$ = $n^{th}$ prime). This was shown by Vinogradov in his attempt to prove Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: @Aryabhata Thanks for the reference. I have edited my answer.