# Generating prime numbers of the form $\lfloor \sqrt{2} \cdot n \rfloor $

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

How to prove the following claims ?

Let $b_n=b_{n-1}+\operatorname{lcm}(\lfloor \sqrt{2} \cdot n \rfloor , b_{n-1})$ with $b_1=2$ and $n>1$ . Let $a_n=b_{n+1}/b_n-1$ .

1. Every term of this sequence $a_i$ is either prime or $1$ .
2. Every odd prime of the form $\left\lfloor \sqrt{2}\cdot n \right\rfloor$ is a term of this sequence.
3. At the first appearance of each prime of the form $\left\lfloor \sqrt{2}\cdot n \right\rfloor$ greater than $5$, it is the next prime of the given form after the largest prime that has already appeared.

A few first terms of this sequence can be found at [A323386](https://oeis.org/A323386) .

Implementation of this generator in PARI/GP can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwlzDEKgDAMheG9p3BMtKLJGnKYRhTEWrXW-2txeQ_-4UvKozgjZXFxvYvWmfIcygwojVuODJuyT95Yjbo47bDE46v3lQswtht6I5SgxoNRT1KF8ylQ3weUDzeu1pnX9GeUF5jAJNE=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: Those questions appear as conjectures on that OEIS page.  Have you got any reason to imagine that the problem is tractable?

Comment: @lulu I think the questioner posted those conjectures on the OEIS page.

Comment: You might be interested in Rowland's sequence: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.html

Comment: Also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122455/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-lfloor-sqrt-3-cdot-n-rfloor?rq=1

Comment: what's special about $\lfloor\sqrt{2n^2}\rfloor$ ?

Comment: Solution to the second claim is posted on an other question of OP.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence